# How to get the PWM output from jsn-sro4t ultrasonic sensor for multiple object detection

Tags: sonarqube

hi I'm using this waterproof ultrasonic sensor jsn-sr04t. I need to build a sonar which can detect multiple object. I used hsr-o4 sensor for multiple ping detection by tapping the op-amp's third pin situated at the center. nut I found it hard to implement the same idea in waterproof sensor. please help.

Comment: Which language are you using? I think your tag is wrong. `Sonarqube` is not the correct tag based on your problem. Please provide more technical detail of your problem. Its looks to me an IoT related problem. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change an onboard resistor to get PWM Output. Can you share pictures of the sensor to verify the exact model you are using?

You can get detailed instructions on how to get PWM output here - [Communicating with Waterproof Ultrasonic Sensor AJ-SR04M/JSN-SR04T with Arduino/ESP32](http://%5Bhttps://tutorials.probots.co.in/communicating-with-a-waterproof-ultrasonic-sensor-aj-sr04m-jsn-sr04t/%5D)